# I need assistance with console applications?

Tags: java

Can any one refer to me some cool or interesting java console applications I can embark on. All I know for now is how to build console applications (am kinda new to java) but I want build something cool all I've been doing in class are basic business applications (pretty boring but helps with java concepts).

Comment: A console application is just a UI - they can still perform any information-processing task. Here's one: build a program that takes in webserver logfiles and generates reports on where visitors are coming from. Make it so it generates pretty charts and graphs.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some fun exercises to help you learn basic OOP techniques and more of the Java programming language.

Poker: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/116864-how-to-make-a-poker-game-in-java/

TicTacToe: https://code.google.com/p/java-console-tictactoe/source/browse/trunk/?r=8

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I highly recommend **[Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/)**, especially if you like math.

Secondly, I suggest building a **TicTacToe program**.  (Enter your move as a number 1-9; the computer updates the screen and checks for win conditions.  Then the other player enters his/her move and the computer updates the screen, etc.)  It's a fun program to write, but can be difficult for some.

An **ATM** is kinda fun, too.  You can get pretty creative with this one--allow yourself to create multiple "accounts," deposit and withdraw cash, etc.  Make sure to include some form of overdraft detection!

Imitating [**Colossal Cave Adventure**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossal_Cave_Adventure) can be fun, too. This is something that can take forever, though.

**Matrix math manipulation** can be a fun exercise, depending on if you like linear algebra or not... `:)`